Macro to update word doc
I have created this Marco to update word doc with Excel. I have embedded the word doc in the Excel and assigned a macro with Command button to activate the Word document. After that I created the subroutine to update the word document with the excel cell reference ( cell A1) to find the matched value with word document particular text and if found paste value that is in next column (let assume cell b1) of sheet in the next para of word document. It is working however there some specified tables in the word document , the sub is pasting value in the next para but not in the table.
Sub UpdateWordDocument3()
      
    Dim selectedValue As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim wordRange As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim description As String
    Dim valueToPaste As String
    Dim oleObject As oleObject
    Dim newWordDoc As Object
    Dim docPath As String
    
    ' Path to the document to be opened
    docPath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\FY25 Feedback Form Digital GAM - Scope and Strategy (FIT Phase 2).docx"
    
    ' Check for any running instances of Word and close them
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Not wordApp Is Nothing Then
        ' Close all open documents without saving
        Do While wordApp.Documents.Count > 0
            wordApp.Documents(1).Close False
        Loop
        wordApp.Quit False
        Set wordApp = Nothing
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Initialize Word application
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = False
    
    ' Get the embedded Word document as an object in the "Landing Page" sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oleObject = Sheets("Landing Page").OLEObjects("Object 9")
    
    If oleObject Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "OLEObject 'Object 9' not found on the 'Landing Page' sheet."
        GoTo ExitSub
    End If
    
    ' Activate the embedded Word document
    oleObject.Activate
    
    ' Set wordDoc object
    Set wordDoc = oleObject.Object
    
    ' Create a new copy of the Word document
    Set newWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    
    ' Copy the content from the embedded Word document
    wordDoc.Range.Copy
    
    ' Paste the content into the new Word document
    newWordDoc.Range.Paste
    
    ' Set font to EYInterstate Light, size 11
    newWordDoc.Content.Font.Name = "EYInterstate Light"
    newWordDoc.Content.Font.Size = 11
    newWordDoc.Content.PreserveFormatting = True
    

    
    ' Close the temporary Word document without saving changes
    wordDoc.Close True
    
    ' Read the value from cell F13 on the "Landing Page" sheet and trim any extra spaces
    selectedValue = Trim(Sheets("Landing Page").Range("$F$13").Value)
    
    ' Check if the selected value matches one of the sheet names
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets(selectedValue)
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The Feedback Form is not found."
        GoTo ExitSub
    End If
    
    ' Constants for Word units
    Const wdParagraph As Long = 4
    
    ' Loop through the cells in column A from A1 to A150 of the selected sheet
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A:A")
               
        description = cell.Value
        valueToPaste = cell.Offset(0, 5).Value ' Value in column E
        
        Select Case cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
            Case "Yes", "N/A"
                ' Find the description in the new Word document
                Set wordRange = newWordDoc.Content
                
                With wordRange.Find
                    .Text = Left(description, 255)
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = 1
                    .Format = False
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                End With
                
                If wordRange.Find.Execute Then
                    ' Remove the entire paragraph that contains the matching value
                    ' until the next table is found
                    Dim startRange As Object
                    Dim endRange As Object
                    Set startRange = wordRange.Paragraphs(1).Range
                    Set endRange = newWordDoc.Range(startRange.Start, newWordDoc.Content.End)
                    wordRange.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
                    
                   
                    If endRange.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                        Set startRange = wordRange.Paragraphs(1).Range
                        Set endRange = newWordDoc.Tables(1).Range
                        newWordDoc.Range(startRange.End, endRange.End).Delete
                    End If
                End If
                
            Case "No"
                ' Find the description in the new Word document
                
                Set wordRange = newWordDoc.Content
                                
                With wordRange.Find
                    .Text = "cell.a320"
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = 1
                    .Format = False
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                End With
                
                     If wordRange.Find.Execute Then
                     If wordRange.Next(wdParagraph).Tables.Count > 0 Then
            ' Paste the value in the respective row and last column
            Dim table As Object
            Set table = wordRange.Next(wdParagraph).Tables(1)
            table.cell(2, 3).Range = valueToPaste
        
                
        End If
    End If

Case "0"
    ' Find the description in the new Word document
    Set wordRange = newWordDoc.Content
    
    With wordRange.Find
        .Text = Left(description, 255)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    
    If wordRange.Find.Execute Then
        ' Paste the value in the next paragraph after the description
        wordRange.Collapse Direction:=0
        wordRange.Text = wordRange.Text & valueToPaste
        wordRange.Font.Bold = False
    End If

               
        End Select
    Next cell
    
    ' Save and open new Word document
    newWordDoc.SaveAs2 docPath
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
ExitSub:
    ' Release objects
    Set wordRange = Nothing
    Set newWordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set oleObject = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    

    Resume ExitSub
End Sub


It's not apparent which line of code you're having trouble with. Presumably something to do with:
   ' Paste the value in the next paragraph after the description
    wordRange.Collapse Direction:=0
    wordRange.Text = wordRange.Text & valueToPaste
    wordRange.Font.Bold = False

I've cleaned up your code and, hopefully, resolved whatever the problem was. You'll see where I've given the option to either insert a new paragraph or replace the content in the next paragraph, depending on that you meant to achieve with the code lines above.
Sub UpdateObjDocument3()

    Dim XlWkSht As Excel.Worksheet, XlCell As Excel.Range
    Dim ObjOLE As oleObject, ObjDocOLE As Object
    Dim ObjWrd As Object, ObjWrdDoc As Object, ObjWrdRng As Object
    Dim StrFnd As String, StrRep As String, r As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Word Constants
    Const wdWithInTable As Long = 12: Const wdCollapseEnd As Long = 0
    Const wdFindContinue As Long = 1: Const wdFindStop As Long = 0
    
    ' Check if the value from cell F13 on the "Landing Page" matches one of the sheet names
    On Error Resume Next
    Set XlWkSht = Sheets(Trim(Sheets("Landing Page").Range("$F$13").Value))
    If XlWkSht Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The Feedback Form is not found.": GoTo ErrExit
    End If
      
    ' Get the embedded Word document as an object in the "Landing Page" sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ObjOLE = Sheets("Landing Page").OLEObjects("Object 9")
    
    If ObjOLE Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "OLEObject 'Object 9' not found on the 'Landing Page' sheet."
        GoTo ErrExit
    End If
    
    ' Initialize Word application
    Set ObjWrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    ObjWrd.Visible = False
    
    ' Activate the embedded Word document
    ObjOLE.Activate
    
    ' Set ObjDoc object
    Set ObjDocOLE = ObjOLE.Object
    
    ' Create a new copy of the Word document
    Set ObjWrdDoc = ObjWrd.Documents.Add
    
    ' Replicate the content in the new Word document
    ObjWrdDoc.Range.FormattedText = ObjDocOLE.Range.FormattedText
    
    ' Close the temporary Word document without saving changes & release memory
    ObjDocOLE.Close False
    Set ObjDocOLE = Nothing: Set ObjOLE = Nothing
   
    ' Loop through the cells in column A from A1 to A150 of the selected sheet
    For Each XlCell In XlWkSht.Range("A:A")
        StrFnd = Left(XlCell.Value, 255)
        StrRep = XlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value ' Value in column E
        
        Select Case XlCell.Offset(0, 4).Value

            Case "Yes", "N/A"
              ' Find the string in the Word document
              With ObjWrdDoc.Range
                  .Find.Execute FindText:=StrFnd, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
                  If .Find.Found Then
                      ' Remove the entire paragraph that contains the matching value
                      ' until the next table is found
                      Set ObjWrdRng = .Paragraphs(1).Range
                      With ObjWrdRng
                          .End = ObjWrdDoc.Range.End
                          If .Tables.Count > 0 Then .End = .Tables(1).Start
                          .Delete
                      End With
                  End If
              End With
                
          Case "No"
          With ObjWrdDoc
              With .Range
                  ' Find all instances of the string in the Word document
                  With .Find
                      .Text = "cell.a320"
                      .Forward = True
                      .Wrap = wdFindStop
                  End With
                  Do While .Find.Execute
                      If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                          ' Paste the value in the respective row and last column
                          r = .Cells(1).RowIndex: c = .Tables(1).Columns.Count
                          .Tables(1).Cell(r, c).Range.Text = StrRep
                      Else
                          ' Replace the value in the next paragraph
                          With .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Characters.Last.Next.Paragraphs.First.Range
                              .Text = StrRep & vbCr
                          End With
                      End If
                      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                  Loop
              End With
          End With

        Case "0"
              ' Find the string in the Word document
              With ObjWrdDoc.Range
                  .Find.Execute FindText:=StrFnd, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
                  If .Find.Found Then
                  ' Insert the value in a new paragraph
                    With .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Next.Paragraphs.First
                      .Text = StrRep
                      .Font.Bold = False
                    End With
                  End If
            End With
        End Select
    Next XlCell
    
    ' Save and open new Word document
    ObjWrdDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\Users\Public\Documents\FY25 Feedback Form Digital GAM - Scope and Strategy (FIT Phase 2).docx"
    ObjWrd.Visible = True
    
ErrExit:
    ' Release objects
    Set ObjWrdRng = Nothing: Set ObjWrdDoc = Nothing: Set ObjWrd = Nothing
    Set XlCell = Nothing: Set XlWkSht = Nothing
End Sub


Can we discussed on live zoom meeting ? i would able to explain more clearly.

See updated answer.

I am having problems with Case 'No' only. Let me explain, Under Case "No" i have want to find with range in coulmn A(there are multiple cells to find with word doument) and paste value in 2 different way. Let assume 1 way is to paster value in the next para . So i used below code and it works
Set wordRange = newWordDoc.Content
                          
                With wordRange.Find
                    .Text = Left(description, 255)
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = 1
                    .Format = False
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                End With
                
  If wordRange.Find.Execute Then
                    ' Paste the value in the next paragraph after the description
                    wordRange.Collapse Direction:=0
                    wordRange.MoveEnd Unit:=4, Count:=1
                    wordRange.Text = wordRange.Text & valueToPaste
                    wordRange.Font.Bold = False
                End If

however there are some para where table are appearing in the word doc and these have 3 columns , i want to paste with under table at specificed row let support ....in excel column a text appearing "A.4" at cell A320 the same text is in word document "A.4" is appearing and there is table after than , so i want to paste value from column E (say cell E320) with  function cell offset (0,5) under row 2 column 3 of the table (2,3) appearing in the word document , then "A.4" is also appearing in cell A321 of in excel now i want to paste value of cell E320 in the "A.4" para appearing in word but now in the table row 3 column 3 (3,3)   . I used the below code but its only pasting value of E319 in row 2 and 3 .....so how can i define multiple criteria for pasting value for example then next criteria for "A.5"..... "? also the how to limit the first criteria .Text = Left(description, 255) to not execute on A.4 , A.5 as its is find a paste funciton for all the value matched
Else
 If wordRange.Find.Execute.Text="A.4" Then
                     If wordRange.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            ' Paste the value in the respective row and last column
            
            Set table = wordRange.Next(wdParagraph).Tables(1)
            table.cell(2,3).Range = valueToPaste
                 

